# NSCoding - initWithCoder and missing properties of object previously coded

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

I have some problem with NSCoding methods.
When I save my custom class it seems everything is ok, it actually create a `.plist` file in my document directory, and this file contain an `NSMutableArray` full of mine custom object.

**Here is the interface and implementation of my custom object**

### .h

```
@interface CustomObj : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

### .m

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{

    [aCoder encodeObject: _titleCobj forKey:@"Title"];

  [aCoder encodeObject: _typeCobj forKey:@"Type"];

   [aCoder encodeObject: _imageCobj forKey:@"Image"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        NSString *title = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Title"];
        self.titleCobj = title;

        NSString *type = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Type"];
        self.typeCobj = type;

        UIImage *image = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Image"];
        self.imageCobj = image;

    }
    return self;
}
```

**Here is the code that I use to find the path for my documents directory**

```
- (NSString *)documentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDirectory;
}

- (NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    return [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favorites.plist"];
}
```

**Here instead the two methods for saving and loading data**

```
- (void)load
{
    NSString *path = [self dataFilePath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSLog (@"<__________________________LOADING__________________________>");

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
        self.favorites = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Favorites"];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];


    } else {

        NSLog (@"<__________________________FIRST TIME LOAD__________________________>");

        self.favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
 }
}


- (void)save
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:_favorites forKey:@"Favorites"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

In my app I have 2 TableViewController.

1. a tableView with 2 custom object (for both object the cell shows an Image, a Label with title and a Label with Type), when i click in a cell this automatically save that object in a "favorites list".
2. and a tableView that load the array of favorites. When I load the array it actually has the correct number of custom object that I had previously saved.

But from the log I could understand that happen something strange:

```
2012-04-15 20:37:52.910 Fav[565:15803] ESISTE un file e l'instance dell'array è ---> (
    "<CustomObj: 0x806d790>",
    "<CustomObj: 0x806d850>",
    "<CustomObj: 0x806d830>",
    "<CustomObj: 0x806d9d0>",
    "<CustomObj: 0x806d9d0>",
)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.910 Fav[565:15803] L'array was loaded, and it is composed by --> 5 objects
2012-04-15 20:37:52.912 Fav[565:15803] INSTANCE CustObj PER CELLA - NUMERO #0_______________
2012-04-15 20:37:52.912 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance title --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.912 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance type --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.913 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance image --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.914 Fav[565:15803] INSTANCE CustObj PER CELLA - NUMERO #1_______________
2012-04-15 20:37:52.914 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance title --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.914 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance type --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.914 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance image --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.915 Fav[565:15803] INSTANCE CustObj PER CELLA - NUMERO #2_______________
2012-04-15 20:37:52.915 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance title --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.915 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance type --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.916 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance image --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.916 Fav[565:15803] INSTANCE CustObj PER CELLA - NUMERO #3_______________
2012-04-15 20:37:52.917 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance title --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.917 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance type --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.917 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance image --> <UIImage: 0x843acf0>
2012-04-15 20:37:52.917 Fav[565:15803] INSTANCE CustObj PER CELLA - NUMERO #4_______________
2012-04-15 20:37:52.918 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance title --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.918 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance type --> (null)
2012-04-15 20:37:52.918 Fav[565:15803] NUOVA INSTANCE - Instance image --> <UIImage: 0x843acf0>
```

I could not understand why all the `ivars` of my `customObj` are nil, but for the last two instances there are actually the Images? my objects are identical, but only for one I can actually load the image and show it in the `tableView`.

I can only imagine that I'm doing something bad with my encoder. I really thank you in advance for the answers :)

Comment: I suspect you have weak references and the objects are being released. Show the declarations of your instance variables (if you've declared them yourself) and the declarations of your properties. If you've implemented the accessors yourself, show those implementations.

Comment: I really thank you were right!! now everything is working fine :)!